# Should a type be move-only, just because copying may be expensive?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have a type that is copyable, but may be expensive to copy. I have implemented the move constructor and move assignment. But I have performance issues where folks forget to call move() when passing by value.

Is it good C++11 style to remove the copy constructor, and instead provide an explicit copy() method for the rare cases when a copy is actually desired? This is idiomatic in other languages (Ruby, JavaScript) but I don't know of anything in the C++ standard library that prohibits copy purely for performance. For instance, std::vector<> is copyable, while std::unique_ptr<> and std::thread are non copyable for other reasons.

Comment: I imagine the problem with a `copy` member function is that it breaks all the template code which uses the assignment operator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Should a type be move-only, just because copying may be expensive?

**No**. If the **semantics** of your type is such that copying it is conceptually meaningful, then the correct way to make copying available is to implement a copy constructor, and give the user a chance to adopt standard syntax for invoking it:

```
T a;
T a = b;
```

If people will forget to move from objects they don't want to use anymore... Well, that's their bad:

```
T c = std::move(a); // I'm doing it right (if I no longer need object a);
T d = b; // If I don't need b anymore, I'm doing it wrong.
```

And if (for any reason) for some functions of yours it is always desirable that the caller provides an object from which it is possible to move, then let the function accept an rvalue reference:

```
void foo(my_class&& obj);

my_class a;
foo(a); // ERROR!
foo(std::move(a)); // OK
```

Comment: In some contexts, copyable types should not be copied via copy construction: `virtual T* Clone() const = 0` for interface classes (or non-final implementations) expresses copyability, yet cannot be implemented as a copy constructor.  Now, `value_ptr<T>` wrappers can return you to the world of copy construction, but the `T` class itself is copyable yet does not have a copy constructor (at least not a public one).

Comment: @Yakk: I don't agree. Any standard container may be pretty expensive to copy, yet it is copyable. Personally, I believe the operation of "copying" has a semantics defined by the language and a syntax defined by the language. Those two things should match.

Comment: I think you meant to comment on my answer, not my comment.  :)

Comment: @Yakk: I commented on the first version of your comment :) You happened to be editing while I was writing the answer, then I submitted and my answer does not match your comment as much as it did before

Comment: In any case, there is precedence in the standard containers: while a forward list has a size, and `size()` could be implemented, it is expensive. So the standard omitted `size()`, and if you want to know the size, you have to do the counting yourself.

Comment: @Yakk: That is a good point. On the other hand, standard containers do not have an *alternative* member function named `compute_size()` instead of the standard `size()`, which would be the parallel of `Clone()` or `Duplicate()` instead of just using a copy constructor. Also, I feel like copying is something much more fundamental than computing size or looking for a value.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to this point of view, that the copy constructor is the supported syntax for a semantically copyable type. However, I find that with C++11, non-copyable types have become a lot more usable. For instance, you no longer need a copy constructor just to put your type in a standard container.

Comment: @TimCulver: Of course non-copyable types have a reason to exist and if something doesn't require a copy, then it shouldn't perform it (I also like move semantics making containers more flexible). My point is rather that if something requires the semantics of copy, that should be provided through the *syntax* of copying.

Answer (score 4):

I would treat the class as non-copyable in signature if copy is sufficiently expensive.  Semantically things are copyable only if you want them to be, and an expensive copy is a decent reason to decide "no, not copyable".

The ability for something to be copied does not mean it need be implemented in a type that is copyable.  The implementer of that type gets to decide if it should be semantically copyable.

I wouldn't call the operation that produced an expensive copy "copy", but rather "clone" or "duplicate".

For a way you might do this:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct DoCopy {
  T const& t;
  DoCopy( T const& t_ ):t(t_) {}
};
template<typename T>
DoCopy<T> do_copy( T const& t ) {
  return t;
}
struct Foo {
  struct ExpensiveToCopy {
    int _[100000000];
  };
  ExpensiveToCopy* data;
  Foo():data(new ExpensiveToCopy()) {}
  ~Foo(){ delete data; }
  Foo(Foo&& o):data(o.data) { o.data = nullptr; }
  Foo& operator=(Foo&& o) { data=o.data; o.data=nullptr; return *this; }
  Foo& operator=(DoCopy<Foo> o) {
    delete data;
    if (o.t.data) {
      data=new ExpensiveToCopy(*o.t.data);
    } else {
      data=new ExpensiveToCopy();
    }
    return *this;
  }
  Foo( DoCopy<Foo> cp ):data(cp.t.data?new ExpensiveToCopy( *cp.t.data ):new ExpensiveToCopy() ) {};
};
int main() {
  Foo one;
  // Foo two = one; // illegal
  Foo three = std::move(one); // legal
  Foo four;
  Foo five = do_copy(three);
  four = std::move(three);
  five = do_copy(four);
}
```

This is somewhat similar to the ways you could have written `std::move` like semantics prior to the existence of rvalue references, with similar downsides to such techniques, namely that the language itself has no idea what shenanigans you are up to.

It has the advantage that the syntax of the above `do_copy` is similar to the syntax of `std::move`, and it allows you to use traditional expressions without having to create trivial instances of `Foo` then construct a copy of another variable etc.

If the situations where we want to treat it as copyable are common (if to be avoided), I'd write a copy-wrapper around the class that knows about the `duplicate` method.

Comment: I'd let the user of my library be the judge.

Comment: I like this solution. I've done something similar for copyable hierarchies, and the move-like syntax is a nice touch.

Answer (score 1):

No. If the type is copyable then the type is copyable. This means its copy constructor is available and *works*. It doesn't mean there's some member function whose name looks like the characters `c`, `o`, `p` and `y` in sequence, that does "sort of nearly a similar thing".

Comment: So, if they disable the copy construction, then the type is not copyable.  It is duplicatable, cloneable, or some other otherwise synonymous verbable -- but clearly not copyable.  How is that a problem?

Comment: @Yakk: I agree with your classification. Is it a problem? Well, who knows? Depends on what you _want_ for your type. But you certainly shall not call it copyable any more, and as far as many many other pieces of code are concerned (e.g. containers), your type simply shall never be copied, because you have decreed it so.

Comment: Right, I don't disagree with the analysis. I'm proposing to make my type non-copyable, despite the fact that it's clearly a value type.